# Disabling networkmanager dispatcher for only the ethernet

Tags: networking, network-manager

I am trying to disable NetworkManager dispatcher scripts using the terminal and enable back dispatcher scripts when i need to. I am fairly new to this kind of stuff and i don't know if its possible or not.
I already found a thread about disabling the dispatcher but it requires me to restart the networkmanager, are there any other ways to disable dispatcher scripts for ethernet without restarting the NetworkManager?

Thanks in advance.